# Django auto assign value to foreign key within a form?

Tags: python, django, database, foreign-keys

I am rendering a form inside of my template where a "patient user" submits an appointment. I have this awkward model hierarchy that I am trying to resolve.

I have an appointmentRequest that takes in a foreign key of the patient where patient consists of a approval number and a foreign key of the user object that is built into django.

I essentially (on form submit for the appointment) to auto fill in the patient foreign key data. Is this possible?

## Models.py

```
#This patient model will extend the user class so we can add the associated medical data for the user
class Patient(models.Model):
    phone_number = PhoneNumberField(blank = True)
    email_address = models.EmailField(blank = True, max_length=254)
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, unique=True,  blank=True, default="", null=True)
    approved = models.IntegerField(default=0, null=False)



#Class for the patients to schedule appointments for their associated doctor
class PatientAppt(models.Model):
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False, unique=True)
    doctor = models.ForeignKey(Doctor, unique=False, blank=True, default="")
    pain_level = models.IntegerField(validators=[MinValueValidator(0),
                                       MaxValueValidator(10)], default=0)
    medical_conditions = models.CharField(max_length=1000, default="None")
    allergies = models.CharField(max_length=1000, default="None")
    user = models.ForeignKey(Patient, unique=False, blank=True, default="")
```

Comment: Please show what you've written for your view so far.

Comment: You can use `initial_data` kwarg while creating the form instance. Or you can also render the foreign key id at HTML side passed through context. There are so many ways!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using django forms (which you should be) I believe the best way is to override the save method and pass the patient object. Passing the id through the form via hidden field means you will need to validate it server side anyways whereas if you pass the id from the session you know it is safe.

```
# Your View
def post(self, request):
    ...
    if context['form'].is_valid():
        context['form'].save(patient=request.user.patient)

# Your form
def save(self, commit=True, patient=patient):
    self.instance.user = patient
    return super(PatientApptForm, self).save(commit=commit)
```